# Load posts via AJAX without draft status

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, ajax, query

When I load posts in the frontend via AJAX, I also see posts that have the status "Draft":

```
function get_projects() {
    $args = array("post_type" => "project");
    $loop = new \WP_Query($args);

    $projects = array();

    while($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();

        $project = '...';
        array_push(projects, $project);
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    echo json_encode($projects);

    die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_projects', 'get_projects');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_projects', 'get_projects');
```

The WordPress doc says the following about this:

> post_status (string / array) – use post status. Retrieves posts by
> post status. Default value is ‘publish‘, but if the user is logged in,
> ‘private‘ is added. Public custom post statuses are also included by
> default. **And if the query is run in an admin context (administration
> area or AJAX call), protected statuses are added too. By default
> protected statuses are ‘future‘, ‘draft‘ and ‘pending**‘.

[Source (WordPress Developer Resources)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters)

Is there any way to prevent the status "protected" from being issued as well?

Comment: if you only want published posts, have you tried explicitly asking `WP_Query` for only posts with the published status?

Answer (score 2):

`admin-ajax.php` is treated as part of the admin, so protected statuses will be included. To solve this just explicitly define `post_status` as `publish` to only get published posts:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
```

Or, better yet, consider using the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) for AJAX requests, instead of the aging admin-ajax.php approach. If you want to query a custom type and receive JSON then you probably don't even need to create your own endpoint.